# Как правильно настроить transaction manager для spring-batch отдельно от JPA?

Tags: java, transaction, springbatch

Приложение на spring4 + jpa + webshere + oracle11g

Есть необходимость настроить работу с фреймворком spring-batch, но
встретил проблему - добавляю spring-batch - перестает работать сохранение JPA сущностей в базу совсем.
В ходе анализа стало понятно, по крайней мере на данный момент,  конфликтуют transaction manager в JPA и Spring-batch

Если делать все по инструкции, например [тут](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/06/spring-batch-2-2-javaconfig-part-3-profiles-and-environments/)

Если в spring-batch использую

```
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
   return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

или
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
       return new WebSphereUowTransactionManager();
    }

то получаю

> Error 500: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>   Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID,
>   JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?];
>   nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table
>   or view does not exist

полный код тут:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(PersistenceConfig.class)
public class BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BatchConfig.class);

    @Getter
    public StringBuilder adminInfo = new StringBuilder();

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;


    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new WebSphereUowTransactionManager();
    }

    public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return  (JobRepository) factory.getObject();
    }

    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }
```

потому что для spring-batch нужна промежуточная таблица которой у меня нет и нет возможности на проде ее создать(нежелательно)

Если я использую transaction manager без ресурсов

```
@Bean
public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
}
```

то получается, что 
работает spring - batch, но перестают сохраняться сущности JPA

полный код тут

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import(PersistenceConfig.class)
public class BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BatchConfig.class);

    @Getter
    public StringBuilder adminInfo = new StringBuilder();

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager);
        mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher simpleJobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        simpleJobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return simpleJobLauncher;
    }
```

в [посте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947970/transaction-management-with-spring-batch) пишут, что происходит переопределение transaction manager ( во втором случае) и поэтому когда приходит время воспользоваться TM из JPA - используется не тот. Не понятно как должно быть правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, все просто, у меня уже есть бин transactionManager созданный для JPA.
Для springBatch создал бин с другим именем и использовал его

```
    @Bean
    public ResourcelessTransactionManager springBatchTransactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

 @Bean
    public JobRepository jobRepository(ResourcelessTransactionManager springBatchTransactionManager) throws Exception {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(springBatchTransactionManager);
        mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(springBatchTransactionManager);
        return mapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
```

Трудность была в том, что в логах никаких ошибок не было и не понятно было куда копать, в конфликт зависимостей или код.